# how to add imagebuttons on horizontal scroll view of tabs so as to scroll on left and right by those image buttons in android studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, horizontalscrollview

**Please help**
Can anyone help me out plz

```
    public class FragmentForScrollBar extends Fragment {
    private HorizontalScrollView hsv;
    Button left, right;
    int currentScrollX = 0;
    Toolbar Toolbar;
    RelativeLayout RelativeLayout;
    ImageButtonhome,player,download,playlist,stream,wish,hit,instrument,news,extras;
    TextView t;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentforscrollbar,null);

        MyPlayer playerFragment = new MyPlayer();
        fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, playerFragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);

        t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);
        home =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonhomea);
        player =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaa);
        playlist =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonca);
        download =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonba);
        stream =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonda);
        wish =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonea);
        hit =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonfa);
        instrument =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonga);
        news =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonha);
        extras =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonia);

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("Home");
                Fragment Home = new Home();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, Home);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
         });
        player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("Player");
                Fragment Myplayer = new MyPlayer();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, Myplayer);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }
        });
        playlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment yourPlayList = new Your_Playlist();
                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, yourPlayList);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("MyDownload");
                Fragment myDownload = new Downloads();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,myDownload);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        stream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("Streaming");
                Fragment uzBek1 = new UzBek();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,uzBek1);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        wish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("Your Wishes");
                Fragment sendWishes = new wishes();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,sendWishes);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
        hit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("Hit Parade");
                Fragment hitParade = new hits();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,hitParade);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        instrument.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("Uzbek Instruments");
                Fragment uzBek1 = new UzBek();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,uzBek1);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        news.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("News");
                Fragment news = new news();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,news);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        extras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setText("Extras");
                Fragment extras = new extras();
                fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, extras);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;

    }
   }
```

[sorry code was too long so i captured the image of the xml module file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc57s.png)

Please see the above code and let me know the solution for scrolling the mini scroll layout on left and right by image buttons.
    I am using two arrow buttons and tell me this also that what to do if i want to hide them in between the scrolling.  Now can someone help me out please

Comment: can you post the xml?

Comment: here's the xml @AbhayBohra u can see in the edit

Comment: R u using tab layout?

Comment: Actually its a relative layout of mini scroll view which looks like a tab layout.

Comment: Use a viewpager with a pagertabstrip for switching fragment tabs. It is more efficient than the current method you are using.

Comment: Thanks, @suku but can you help me with the current one problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might be puzzled up with the same issue:

```
public class FragmentForScrollBar extends Fragment {


SeekBar verticalSeekBar=null;

private HorizontalScrollView hsv, hsv2;

Toolbar Toolbar;


ImageButton home,player,download,playlist,stream,wish,hit,instrument,news,extras, bP,bN;
ImageButton homea,playera,downloada,playlista,streama,hita,wisha,instrumenta,newsa, extrasa;
TextView t;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentforscrollbar,null);

    MyPlayer playerFragment = new MyPlayer();
    fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, playerFragment, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);

    t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);
    home =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonhomea);
    player =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaa);
    playlist =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonca);
    download =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonba);
    stream =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonda);
    wish =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonea);
    hit =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonfa);
    instrument =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonga);
    news =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonha);
    extras =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonia);


    playera =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonaab);
    playlista =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtoncab);
    downloada =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonbab);
    streama =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtondab);
    wisha =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtoneab);
    hita =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonfab);
    instrumenta=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtongab);
    newsa =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonhab);
    extrasa =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtoniab);


    verticalSeekBar=(SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


    ImageButton bP = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.left);
    ImageButton bN = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.right);

    bP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //value 500 is arbitrarily given. if you want to achieve
            //element-by-element scroll you should get the width of the
            //previous element dynamically or if the elements of the
            //list have uniform width just put that value instead
            hsv.scrollTo(0,-500);
            //if it's the first/last element you can bPrevoius.setEnabled(false)

        }
    });


    bN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hsv.scrollTo(500,0);

        }
    });
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Home");
            Fragment Home = new Home();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, Home);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            // fragmentTransaction.popBackStack();
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            //  t.setText("Player");
        }
    });
    player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Player");
            Fragment Myplayer = new MyPlayer();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, Myplayer);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
           // fragmentTransaction.popBackStack();
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
    });
    playlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //  DrawerNavigation mainActivity = new DrawerNavigation();
          //  mainActivity.drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Fragment yourPlayList = new Your_Playlist();
            fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, yourPlayList);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

          // t.setText("PlayList");
        }
    });
    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("MyDownload");
            Fragment myDownload = new Downloads();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,myDownload);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    stream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Streaming");
            Fragment uzBek1 = new UzBek();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,uzBek1);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    wish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Your Wishes");
            Fragment sendWishes = new wishes();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,sendWishes);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
    hit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Hit Parade");
            Fragment hitParade = new hits();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,hitParade);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    instrument.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Uzbek Instruments");
            Fragment uzBek1 = new UzBek();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,uzBek1);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    news.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("News");
            Fragment news = new news();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,news);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    extras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText("Extras");
            Fragment extras = new extras();
            fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, extras);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

}

Just add image buttons on both ends and seOnclickListener() on them then scroll them up to a desired value as shown in the code.